# Using Recursion, how do I get my code to reiterate?

Tags: python, if-statement, recursion

My assignment is to find out how many times it takes for num1 to be divided by num2 before its a whole number, using recursion. My current code is

```
def fraction_count(num1, num2):
    times = int(0)
    result = num1/num2
    num1 = int(result)
    if result%2 == 0:
        return times
    if (num1/num2)%2 != 0:
        return times + 1
print(fraction_count(32,3))
```

Expected is:

```
fraction_count(32, 3) → 2 # 32 → 10.667 → 3.333 → 1; 1 is whole → 2
```

So I have the output of 1 right now because its just running through once. What am I missing here?

Comment: there is no recursive call anywhere?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thats what Im struggling with is how to make a recursive call. I figured the first if statement would be the base case

Comment: The base case is wrong. You want to know if `num1 / num2` has a zero remainder, not if the quotient is even.

Comment: Your function is `function_count`, so a recursive call would just be a call to `function_count(q)` for some appropriate argument `q`.

Comment: Are `num1` and `num2` guaranteed to be integers? If so, you should be doing integer division with `//` to get `32 → 10 → 3`, which requires two divisions to get to an integer multiple of `num2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Riffing off of Nin17's answer but fulfilling the assignment's requirement to make it recursive yields:

```python
def fraction_count(num1, num2):
    num1 = int(num1)
    num2 = int(num2)
    if num1 % num2 == 0:
        return 0
    return 1 + fraction_count(num1 // num2, num2)
```

You can make it a tad faster by eliminating the type conversions if `num1` and `num2` are guaranteed to be integers. With type hinting (added in python 3.5), the code becomes:

```python
def fraction_count(num1: int, num2: int) -> int:
    if num1 % num2 == 0:
        return 0
    return 1 + fraction_count(num1 // num2, num2)
```

Short and sweet. Recursion may be less efficient than looping, but it often delivers concise code.

Answer (score 0):

The question is confusing, but this implements something similar to your example and provides the desired result for `fraction_count(32, 3)`

```
def fraction_count(num1, num2):
    num1 = int(num1)
    num2 = int(num2)
    count = 0
    while num1 % num2:
        num1 //= num2
        count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: Where is `fraction_count` inside the body of your function?

Comment: Nowhere, tbh I don't understand the original question at all

Comment: I cant use for/while loops